# WCF Service: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: wcf, getjson

I am trying to programm a test app with a client/server principle. The server is a simple WCF service which works (CRUD -> Create, Read, Udate, Delete) with an entity model.

On the client side I have this function which passes the data (in json format) to the WCF service:

```
save: function (w) {

    var object= [{
        "id": w.id,
        "date": w.date,
        "content": w.content
    }];

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:49817/Service.svc/SaveObject/" + object).done(function (data) {
        App.content.setObject(data);
    });
},
```

And here is the WCF service:

```
public string SaveObject(string object)
    {
        try
       {
            CustomClass myCustom= (CustomClass) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(object, typeof (JObject));

            using (AppEntities entities = new AppEntities())
            {
                CustomClass newCustom = new CustomClass();

                newCustom.id = newCustom.id;
                newCustom.date= myCustom.date;
                newCustom.content = myCustom.content;

                entities.Wertungen.Add(newWertung);
                entities.SaveChanges();

                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new FaultException("An error occured during saving the new object");             
        }
    }
```

My problem is that always in this part here

**CustomClass myCustom= (CustomClass) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(object, typeof (JObject));**

an error occured: **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value**.

I don't know the error. I have tried now since a few days and haven't a solution till today.
I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: whats the content of object when the request is performed ? and you should rename it to @object because object is a already named type. Furthermore how does this even compile ? it should give an error that "object" is a keyword

Comment: Can you double-check that you're actually parsing valid json using fiddler or something similar? I've had this happen to me where I thought I got json but I actually got an error message formatted as HTML.

Comment: @Mark: I just have changed the name from the orignal to object. This one here is a short example of what I want to do. The content of "object" is **object Object** after the request.

Comment: @Ola Ekdahl: That's a bit strange. I have made a function who checks if the string is valid json format. I have done it with two alert boxes. First it means it's false and then directly afterwards it means it is true...

Comment: So what does the input string to SaveObject(string object) look like if you step through with a debugger?

Comment: @Ola Ekdahl: If I step through with a debugger, the string object looks like **object Object**.

Comment: alert(JSON.Stringfy(object))...... this will help you to know whats json data...please check date object is passing correct